# Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/NodeJS/index.js' + 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload by MEAN app to AWS (elastic beanstalk) but am getting the error below, and my website is displaying `502 bad gateway`

I'm not sure where it came up with the path `/var/app/current/NodeJS/index.js`, is this correct?

[image]

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------

Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/NodeJS/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/NodeJS/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your package.json file looks like?